# How to finish an activity from a ListView adapter class?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have an activity with a ListView that loads data from a web service. I have a button in each list item which is loaded through custom adapter class. I am handling the button events in the adapter class. Now what I need is to finish the activity with ListView from the adapter class in the button click event.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((Activity)context).finish();

                }
            });
```

use this code on button click event

Answer (score 0):

You can use `((Activity)context).finish();` method.

Answer (score 0):

Get you activity context, and after that you can do your_context.finish().